# IList<T> and List<T> Conversions with Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, polymorphism

I generally understand interfaces, inheritance and polymorphism, but one thing has me puzzled.

In this example, **Cat** implements **IAnimal** and of course **List** implements **IList**:

```
IList<IAnimal> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

but it generates a compilation error *(Cannot implicitly convert type...)*. It also won't work if I use an asbtract superclass [Animal] that Cat inherits from. However, If I replace **IAnimal** with **Cat**:

```
IList<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

it compiles fine.

In my mind, because **Cat** implements **IAnimal**, the first example *should* be acceptable, allowing us to return an interface for both the list and the contained type.

Can anyone explain why it isn't valid? I'm sure there's a logical explanation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a logical explanation, and this exact question is asked pretty much every day on StackOverflow.

Suppose this was legal:

```
IList<IAnimal> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

What stops this from being legal?

```
cats.Add(new Giraffe());
```

Nothing. "cats" is a list of animals, and a giraffe is an animal, and therefore you can add a giraffe to a list of cats.

Clearly that is not typesafe.

In C# 4 we added a feature whereby you can do that if the metadata annotations allow the compiler to prove that it is typesafe. In C# 4 you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<IAnimal> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

because `IEnumerable<IAnimal>` has no Add method, so there is no way to violate type safety.

See my series of articles on how we designed this feature in C# 4 for more details.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx

(Start from the bottom.)

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'll definitely be reading your articles. Also apologies for asking a constantly repeated question too... will do a much better search next time.

Comment: @Mark: You're welcome, and no worries; the fact that this question is asked so much is one of the things that motivated adding the feature to C# 4 in the first place. Clearly people have an intuition that generic variance ought to be a part of the type system. Now it is just a matter of educating people about what kinds of variance are provably safe.

Comment: An update. I have now read Eric's articles and they clear up covariance and contravariance perfectly. I also read the section on this in C# in Depth by Jon Skeet, which provides a nice summary too (and tactics to deal with covariance and contravariance). Anyone else struggling with the concept should look no further than these two resources in my opinion. Thanks to everyone who offered guidance.

Answer (score 6):

C# doesn't support this kind of variance on `IList<T>` for type-safety reasons.

If C# did support this, what would you expect to happen here?

```
IList<IAnimal> cats = new List<Cat>();

cats.Add(new Dog());         // a dog is an IAnimal too
cats.Add(new Squirrel());    // and so is a squirrel
```

In C#4 you're able to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<IAnimal> cats = new List<Cat>();
```

This is because the `IEnumerable<T>` interface does support variance of this kind. An `IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only sequence, so there's no way that you could subsequently add a `Dog` or a `Squirrel` to an `IEnumerable<IAnimal>` that's actually a list of `Cat`.

Answer (score 1):

This type of [covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) is not supported in C# 4.0.  It is reasonable to expect the behavior you want, it just isn't supported (for now).

Comment: Can you clarify?  Covariance and contravariance are supported in C# 4.0, but IList<T> is not a covariant interface.

Comment: Haha, well, Eric Lippert just answered, so I think that about sums it up :D

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using LINQ:

```
IList<IAnimal> cats = new List<Cat>().Cast<IAnimal>();
```

Answer (score 1):

`IList<T>` is not a covariant interface (or it would be `IList<out T>`).  This is because IList both takes type `T` as a parameter and returns it as a return value from methods, which makes covariance problematic.

For example, if in your example:

`IList<IAnimal> cats = new List<Cat>();`

You wanted to add a new cat, from cats, it would allow:

`cats.Add(new Dog());`

assuming Dog also implemented IAnimal, this is obviously incorrect and wouldn't work.  Which is why IList is not a covariant or contravariant interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you need covariance and contravariance on a list-like interface, you should define an interfaces IReadableList<out T> and IWritableList<in T>, and derive a type from List<T> which implements both ReadableList<T&, and WriteableList<T>.  This would then make it possible to pass a NewList<Cat> to a routine which expects a ReadableList<Animal> or a WritableList<SiameseCat>.